# Rake task to backup in-memory sqlite database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake-task

I was wondering how to write a rake task for backing up the default rails database. I tried the following. However, nothing seems to be getting written in the file.

```
namespace :mockdb do
 desc "Back up the database"
  task :backup => :environment do
    puts "Backing up the database.."
    system "sqlite3 .dump > #{dump_path}"
    puts "Phew! All data has been backed up!"
 end

 def dump_path
  Rails.root.join('db/mock.sql').to_path
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the system was not able to find sqlite3. I had to give the installation path. Following is the final snippet

```
namespace :mockdb do
  sqlite_path = "/usr/bin/sqlite3"
  sql_file = "db/#{Rails.env}.sqlite3"

 desc "Back up the database"
  task :backup => :environment do
    puts "Backing up the database.."
    system "#{sqlite_path} #{sql_file} .dump > #{dump_path}"
    puts "All data has been backed up!"
  end

 def dump_path
  Rails.root.join('db/mock.sql').to_path
 end
end
```